# Oracle SQL- Stack dates if they match diagonally

Tags: sql, oracle

The goal is to stack dates if DT and VAR are same, and  END_DATE matches the START_DATE of next highest START_DATE
In the example, row 2 and 3 are combined because END_DATE of row 2 matches START_DATE of row 3.

Original

```
|DT         | START_DATE | END_DATE   | VAR |
|---------- |----------- |------------|---- |
|15-JUN-21  |01-JAN-20   |  01-JAN-21 | A   |
|15-JUN-21  |02-JAN-20   |  10-JAN-20 | A   |
|15-JUN-21  |10-JAN-20   |  01-JAN-21 | A   |
|22-JUN-21  |01-JAN-21   |  31-DEC-99 | A   |
```

Expected

```
|DT         | START_DATE | END_DATE   | VAR |
|----------  |-----------|----------- |---- |
|15-JUN-21  |01-JAN-20   |  01-JAN-21 | A   |
|15-JUN-21  |02-JAN-20   |  01-JAN-21 | A   |
|22-JUN-21  |01-JAN-21   |  31-DEC-99 | A   |
```

I have tried the query below but the solution won't work when there is additional rows.

```
WITH T1 as (
SELECT 
t.*, row_number() over (partition by VAR,DT
                    order by start_date  -- anything can go here
                 )  rnum 
FROM T_STACK t)
, T2 as (
SELECT 
A.DT
,A.START_DATE
,CASE WHEN A.END_DATE = B.START_DATE THEN B.END_DATE
ELSE A.END_DATE END END_DATE
,A.VAR
,A.RNUM r1
,B.RNUM r2
FROM T1 A
LEFT JOIN T1 B
ON A.VAR = B.VAR
AND A.END_DATE = B.START_DATE
AND A.DT = B.DT
AND B.rnum = A.rnum+1
)

SELECT * FROM T2
WHERE r1 < 3
ORDER BY START_DATE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I think the simplest way is to use `lag()` and date comparisons to define where a group begins.  Then use a cumulative sum to define the groups and aggregate:

```
select dt, var, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date = start_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by dt, var, grp;
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution is not long and easily understandable. I will test with more input.

Comment: I think it is working. I am confused how grp is working. If I add, `15-JUN-21 11-JAN-20 15-JAN-20 A 01-JAN-21` The grp is coming as 3. Why is that the case.

Comment: Please ignore 01-Jan-21 at end above.  `15-JUN-21 11-JAN-20 15-JAN-20 A`

Comment: @Sxc-Dev . . . Your question is quite explicit that the end date needs to match the next start date ("END_DATE matches the START_DATE of next highest START_DATE").  If you have a different question (say arbitrary overlaps), then ask a *new* question.

Comment: It is not a new question. I am just requesting explanation of `sum(case when prev_end_date = start_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date) as grp` in your original answer. or More specifically why "grp" is returning new value for each pair (which is correct).

Comment: I found the reason why grp is returning new value for each pair. When using `order by` clause in analytical function that supports windowing clause. The oracle uses the default windowing clause, `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW `. It looks at first row based on `partition by` and `order by` clause up to the current row so it returns new value and not duplicate when using SUM() analytical function.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to approach gaps-and-islands problems, but I think some will struggle with the overlapping dates you're keeping - the second row in your expected result fits entirely within the first, for example.

This uses lead and lag:

```
select distinct dt,
  case when t_start is null
    then lag(t_start) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
    else t_start
  end as start_date,
  case when t_end is null
    then lead(t_end) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
    else t_end
  end as end_date,
  var
from (
  select dt, start_date, end_date, var,
    case when start_date = lag(end_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
      then null else start_date end as t_start,
    case when end_date = lead(start_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
      then null else end_date end as t_end
  from t_stack
)
where t_start is not null or t_end is not null
order by dt, start_date, end_date;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9bc2b924a69aa4ccc09b40aa5d6e2f61) with some additional data to show several contiguous ranges collapsed to one.

Breaking that down:

```
select dt, start_date, end_date, var,
  case when start_date = lag(end_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
    then null else start_date end as t_start,
  case when end_date = lead(start_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
    then null else end_date end as t_end
from t_stack
order by dt, start_date, end_date
```

uses ​lead/lag to null the start/end dates if they match the adjacent values, giving (with the extra data):

```
DT        | START_DATE | END_DATE  | VAR | T_START   | T_END    
:-------- | :--------- | :-------- | :-- | :-------- | :--------
15-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-20  | 01-JAN-21 | A   | 01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-21
15-JUN-21 | 02-JAN-20  | 10-JAN-20 | A   | 02-JAN-20 | null     
15-JUN-21 | 10-JAN-20  | 01-JAN-21 | A   | null      | 01-JAN-21
22-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-21  | 31-DEC-99 | A   | 01-JAN-21 | 31-DEC-99
29-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-21  | 01-FEB-21 | A   | 01-JAN-21 | null     
29-JUN-21 | 01-FEB-21  | 01-MAR-21 | A   | null      | null     
29-JUN-21 | 01-MAR-21  | 01-APR-21 | A   | null      | null     
29-JUN-21 | 01-APR-21  | 01-JAN-22 | A   | null      | 01-JAN-22
```

Then any rows where both adjusted dates are null are in the middle of a contiguous run, so they can be thrown away:

```
select dt, t_start, t_end, var
from (
 ​select dt, start_date, end_date, var,
   ​case when start_date = lag(end_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
     ​then null else start_date end as t_start,
   ​case when end_date = lead(start_date) over (partition by dt, var order by start_date)
     ​then null else end_date end as t_end
 ​from t_stack
)
where t_start is not null or t_end is not null
order by dt, start_date, end_date
```

```
DT        | T_START   | T_END     | VAR
:-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--
15-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-21 | A  
15-JUN-21 | 02-JAN-20 | null      | A  
15-JUN-21 | null      | 01-JAN-21 | A  
22-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-21 | 31-DEC-99 | A  
29-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-21 | null      | A  
29-JUN-21 | null      | 01-JAN-22 | A
```

And then the final query uses lead/lag again, but now it fill in the null values. That gives duplicates, which `distinct` removes, giving:

```
DT        | START_DATE | END_DATE  | VAR
:-------- | :--------- | :-------- | :--
15-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-20  | 01-JAN-21 | A  
15-JUN-21 | 02-JAN-20  | 01-JAN-21 | A  
22-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-21  | 31-DEC-99 | A  
29-JUN-21 | 01-JAN-21  | 01-JAN-22 | A
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I appreciate it.